# CloudFormation Scripting - Copy AMI

Tags: yaml, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ami

Can someone guide me on how to create a CLoudFormation Template in YAML Format to copy/encrypt a shared private AMI from my AWS account? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you encrypting, attached storage or instance storage?  You can use snapshots

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb it was a shared custom AMI from other account that was shared with my AWS Account. The output AMI was build from the other account using EC2 Image Builder. I just need help on how to create or a sample CloudFormation Template to Copy and Encrypt that shared AMI to me.

Comment: AWS CloudFormation can be used to create and launch infrastructure, but it cannot be used to run actions, such as 'copying' an AMI. You could add a Lambda Custom Resource that can run commands for you, but this involves more work. Do you wish to copy the AMI every time this stack is launched, or just use it?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein hmm okay so a Lambda function will do the copy image action as I've understand not the CF itself. I just need a ready template for me to encrypt the shared AMI (built from EC2 Image Builder) to my account (target) that was not encrypted yet after it was share from the other source account.

Comment: You can't do this using vanial CFN and there is no ready template for that. Have to develop a custom resource in CFN  tailored specifically to your needs.

Comment: @Marcin yes agreed that there's no CFN template yet on this one. So I tried to post here if someone can share a sample template.

Comment: @Nadnad I just [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61926019/248823) general guideline on development of a custom resource for other question. Following it will should be helpful for development of your own custom resource.

Comment: If you change/migrate the storage to EBS, you can easily copy https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/CopyingAMIs.html#ami-copy-steps